# How to keep geospatial data when converting GTiff to PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, geospatial, gdal, geotiff

I'm working with some custom maps that I've made. They are saved locally as a GTiff and, when drag-dropping them on Google Earth, align beautifully on the map. I now want to convert them to Geospatial PDF and cannot get the geodata to follow to the PDF. Code:

```
from osgeo import gdal

pdfTarget = 'pdf/output.pdf'
mapSource = 'map_images/input.tif'

# Create PDF file from GeoTIFF map
gdal.Translate(pdfTarget,
                    mapSource,
                    outputSRS='EPSG:4326')
```

If I change the file ending to .tif in pdfTarget, a GTiff is created and the georeferencing works.

Any help in converting the GTiff to PDF would be greatly appreciated, it doesn't have to be in GDAL.

Comment: Thank you. Is GeoPDF the same thing as a geospatial PDF, or is it a brand name for a PDF that happens to be geospatial? I mean; if I georeference a PDF, is it a proprietary GeoPDF by default and not just a georeferenced PDF? Hope you see what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: I suspected that. So, is there a good way for me to convert the GeoTiff map to a PDF? The reason for it is that I need to embed the map on a third PDF page and keep the georeference data.